# Gerar número de matrícula sequencial

Tags: java

Olá, estou tentando criar uma método em java que vai gerar uma matrícula sequencial baseada no ano que será fornecido pelo usuário.

Por exemplo se o aluno cadastrado for o primeiro do ano 2021, ele vai receber uma matrícula 20210001, se ele for o primeiro de 2022, ele vai receber 20220001, se for o segundo 20220002.

O programa vai pedir para o usuário inserir os dados do aluno e no final vai mostrar a matrícula gerada e então o usuário vai poder sair ou continuar.

Se o usuário continuar e escolher sempre o mesmo valor pro ano, o programa funciona corretamente, ele fornece de maneira sequencial a matrícula.
Se ele tentar usar um outro ano tipo 2022, o programa fornece 20220001, porém  se ele quiser cadastraum outro aluno de 2021, após esse de 2022, o programa não fornece a matrícula correta, ele volta pro inicio e imprimi 20210001.

Então basicamente o problema é que o programa reseta a matrícula depois que tem a entrada de um valor diferente pra variável ano.

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer o sistema "lembrar" onde que parou a sequência do outro ano. Eu tentei de algumas formas, mas eu acabava me limitando em só dois anos, o sistema voltava a dar erro se eu tentasse cadastrar um terceiro ano.

```
public class Aluno extends Pessoa{
    
    public static int matricula;
    public static int anoLetivo;
    public static int contador=0;
    public static int i=0;

    
    Aluno(String nome, int idade, int ano){
        super(nome, idade);
        setContador(ano);
        anoLetivo = ano;
    }
    
    public static int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    
    public void setMatricula(int ano) {
        if(ano != anoLetivo && anoLetivo > 0) {
            contador = 0;
            contador++;
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
            }
        else if(ano == anoLetivo && anoLetivo > 0) {
            contador++;
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
        }
        else {
            contador = 1;
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
        }
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        String nome;
        int i=0;
        int idade;
        int ano;
        int op;
        
        Aluno aluno[] = new Aluno[10];
        Administrador admin[] = new Administrador[5];
                
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do{ 
            System.out.print("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
            nome = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Digite a idade: ");
            idade = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Digite o ano de ingresso: ");
            ano = scanner.nextInt();
        
            aluno[i] = new Aluno(nome, idade, ano);
        
            System.out.println("Matrícula de "+aluno[i].nome+": "+Aluno.getMatricula());
        
            System.out.print("Digite 1 para continuar ou qualquer outro número para sair: ");
            op = scanner.nextInt();
        
            System.out.println();
        }while(op==1);
        System.out.println("Sistema encerrado!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

#### Estratégia da resolução do problema.

Grave o contador em um `map`. Um `map` tem um índice e um valor. Como se fosse uma tabela de 2 colunas.

Exemplo:

```
2021 50
2022 20
2023 3
```

assim por diante.
Ou seja, se você armazena até o 20 no ano de 2022, e volta em 2021, ele vai voltar e colocar 51 e não 1, 2, etc.

Dessa forma você não vai voltar a `0` como o `contador` está fazendo.

#### Como implementar isso?

##### Passo 1:

Declare um atributo de classe:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> contador = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

##### Passo 2

No `setMatricula` adicione (ideia em pseudo código):

```
se (map contador tem indice do ano) 
   obtem contador
senão 
   obtem 1 e grava no map ("tabela" de controle)
```

###### implementando passo 2:

```
if (contador.containsKey(ano)){
    // obtem o atual e atualiza o contador
    int atual = contador.get(ano) + 1; // vai salvar esse atual
    contador.put(ano, atual);
    // segue gerando a matricula com esse contador
} else {
    int atual = 1;
    contador.put(ano, atual);
    // segue gerando a matricula com esse contador
}
```

Agora lembrando... se precisar de gravar o contador e o programa fechar e abrir novamente e continuar o mesmo, precisa gravar em arquivo ou banco.

Comment: Top demais, deu certinho, valeu!

Comment: Eu não entendo muito do fórum e queria entender porque mesmo o autor da pergunta aceitando a solução, está com nota -2 de pessoas que avaliaram mal a resposta. Se tem motivos, eu gostaria de entender o porquê.

Answer (score -2):

Seu problema está no sua condicional dentro da validação da matricula,
como ele verifica somente o valor do anoLetivo estatico o contador é resetado

```java
 if(ano != anoLetivo && anoLetivo > 0) {
            contador = 0;
            contador++;
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
            }
```

Fiz um pseudo codigo para voce ver como ficaria
uma solução que você poderia fazer é utilizar Hashmap para salvar a contagem de alunos

```java
//Classe Aluno
Public cass Aluno extends Pessoa{

private Map<Integer,Integer> contador_ano;

//Construtor
    Aluno(....,Map<Integer,Integer> anos){
    // outros inits
     this.anos = anos;

   }


//More Code....


    public void setMatricula(int ano) {
        if(ano != anoLetivo && anoLetivo > 0) {
            // Tenta Pegar o Ano do aluno
            contador = contador_ano.contains(ano) ? contador_ano.get(ano) : 0;
            contador++;
            contador_ano.put(ano,contador);
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
            }
        else if(ano == anoLetivo && anoLetivo > 0) {
            contador++;
            contador_ano.put(ano,contador);
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
        }
        else {
            contador = 1;
            contador_ano.put(ano,contador);
            matricula = (ano * 10000) + contador;
        }
    }


}

//Classe main

public class Main {

    public void main(args[]) {

        Map < Integer, Integer > anos = new HashMap < > ();
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome, idade, ano, anos);

        Integer matricula = Aluno.getMatricula();

        system.println(matricula.toString());


    }

}
```

A ideia é simples crie uma Hashmap statico no seu codigo e compartilhe ele com todas as suas instancias de Alunos e verifique se o ano existe neste hashmap se sim puxe o ultimo registro se não adicione o registro no hashmap.
Provaelmente você vai precisar fazer mais ajustes no seu codigo para comportar
mas este é o caminho de uma das soluções possiveis

```
contador = contador_ano.contains(ano) ? contador_ano.get(ano) : 0;
```

Caso não tenha conhecimento sobre hashmap vale a leitura
[Link HashMap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: Obrigadão mano!